# In VIM, how to join next line when current line does not end with space 

Tags: regex, vi

In vim , what command should be used if I wanna join next line when current line does not end with space.

original text:

```
aaaa(space)
bbbbx
cccc
```

after command :

```
aaaa(space)
bbbbxcccc
```

`:g/^.*(!\s)$/,/./-j` gives error

I am not familiar with VI. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is a little bit special in VI.
You have to escape some operations. Therefore use `\v` at the beginning of your pattern, if you want normal behaviour.

The following pattern does what you want:

```
:%s/\v( \n)|\n/\1/g
```

As you can see there is a `%s` in front of it. Which is similar to sed. Instead of `%` you can also use `2,3` which are lines, where the regex should be executed.